# How to get full path of a file just by giving the filename in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I have a file path as C:\Sample\example.txt.

how can full path of the file be retrieved (the file can be in any directory) just by giving the filename i.e., example.txt  in C ?

Comment: Do you mean: how do you search for that file in a directory tree?

Comment: That is called recursive file search. if your OS has an indexing utility, use it. but you should handle the case where there is several 'example.txt' around. also, what OS are you using ?

Comment: How would the computer know you want "C:\Sample\example.txt" and not (the also existing) "C:\some\other\directory\example.txt"?

Comment: dir /s/b>file.txt gives the current directory all folders and sub folders

Answer (score 0):

get the source for the "find" command from the (i think) gnu package (or a linux source distribution), and copy the appropriate passages for you platform.